# How to retrieve data of 2 record ids using SOQL query

Tags: apex, visualforce

The aim of this code is to retrieve the ticket information of the two record ids in the **List recordids = new List();** How can i write this code for best for practice.

```
public Static List<String> getrecordidlist(String textsearch)
{
    String newtextsearch = '%'+textsearch+'%';
    list<String> listid = new List<String>();
    for(Contact con : [Select Id from Contact where Name like :newtextsearch])
    {
        listid.add(String.valueOf(con.Id));    
    }
    return listid;
}
 Public Static list<Ticket__c> getTicketRecord(String textsearch)
{
    List<String> listid = getrecordidlist(textsearch);
    List<Ticket__c> ticketinfo ;
    for(integer i = 0; i<=listid.size()-1; i++)
    {
       ticketinfo = [Select Ticket_ID__c,Booker__c,Ticket_holder__c from Ticket__c where Booker__c=:listid[i]]; 
    }
    return ticketinfo;
}
```

Comment: quick suggestion. NEVER hardcode Id's and NEVER use SOQL/SOSL queries in loops. Hardcoding Id's will break the deployment of code and using queries in loops will hit the SF limits.

Comment: Tnx for the suggestion sam. Now i edit my code so that you can see and suggest how to impelement my codes for retrieving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below code as per your above code design:

```
public Static List<String> getrecordidlist(String textsearch)
{
String newtextsearch = '%'+textsearch+'%';
list<String> listid = new List<String>();
   for(Contact con : [Select Id from Contact where Name like :newtextsearch])
  {
    listid.add(String.valueOf(con.Id));    
   }
    return listid;
}
 public static list<Ticket__c> getTicketRecord(String textsearch)
{
    return [Select Ticket_ID__c,Booker__c,Ticket_holder__c from 
            Ticket__c where Booker__c IN :getrecordidlist(textsearch)]; 
}
```

> SOQL statements can't exceed 20,000 characters. For SOQL statements
>   that exceed the maximum length of characters, then the API returns a MALFORMED_QUERY
>   exception code ; no result rows are returned.

Let me know in case of any other help!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm)

```
public Static set<Id> getrecordIdSet(String textsearch)
{
  String newtextsearch = '%'+textsearch+'%';
  set<Id> contactIds = new set<Id>();
  for(Contact con : [Select Id from Contact where Name like :newtextsearch])
  {
    contactIds.add(con.Id);    
  }
  return contactIds;
}
Public Static list<Ticket__c> getTicketRecord(String textsearch)
{
 set<Id> contactIdSet = getrecordIdSet(textsearch);
 List<Ticket__c> ticketinfo = [Select Ticket_ID__c,Booker__c,Ticket_holder__c from Ticket__c where Booker__c IN : contactIdSet]; 
 return ticketinfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  use `IN` clause. Example:

```
List<String> listId = new List<String>();
listId.add('003xcc00000322');
listId.add('003xcc00000988');


ticketinfo = [Select id from Ticket__c where id IN:listId];
```